# Update a field if contacts don't exist in a data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I have:

One Data Extension **(Time_Throttling)** with all contact details.

Another DE **(Time_Throttling_Transfer)** that basically has some data from Time_Throttling.

Now I have to update a boolean field to True in Time_Throttling for all records which are not in Time_Throttling_Transfer .
I'm using this query

```sql
select t.pkey, 'True' as [t.Check_Yesterday] from Time_Throttling t
left join Time_Throttling_Poc t
on tt.pkey = t.pkey
```

This query however doesn't update the field as required.

Answer (score 1):

You're close, but you don't have any exclusionary criteria in your query and the DE names don't match with your description above. To filter out only those records that have a match, you'd need to use `LEFT JOIN WHERE NULL` logic such as:

```
SELECT t.pkey
    ,'True' AS [t.Check_Yesterday]
FROM Time_Throttling t
LEFT JOIN Time_Throttling_Transfer t ON tt.pkey = t.pkey
WHERE t.pkey IS NULL
```

I'd recommend checking out a tutorial on using [LEFT JOIN](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-left-join/) in order to see why the above logic didn't execute as intended. Also, while there are many ways to accomplish the above criteria, I find that it's much easier to use `NOT EXISTS` when creating exclusionary logic like the above. It accomplishes the same functionality and is, in my opinion, easier to read.

```
SELECT t.pkey
    ,1 AS [t.Check_Yesterday]
FROM Time_Throttling t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Time_Throttling_Transfer AS tt
        WHERE tt.pkey = t.pkey
        )
```